# Problem with VBA script reading from MySql database

Tags: mysql, vba, excel, excel-2007

I am having some trouble with a vba script in Excel which should be
reading from a MySql database.  The SQL query should only return one
record but actually returns an empty resultset. The generated statement works fine when run through phpMyAdmin.

Here is my code:

```
Function getClientId(emailAddress As String)
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sql As String

    ConnectDB

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    sql = "SELECT client_id FROM clients WHERE email_address = '" & emailAddress & "' LIMIT 1"
    Debug.Print sql
    rs.Open sql, oConn

    Debug.Print rs.RecordCount

    If (rs.RecordCount = -1) Then
        getClientId = Null
    Else
        getClientId = rs(0)
    End If
    rs.Close
End Function
```

EDIT: My database connect function.

```
Function ConnectDB()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
    oConn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};" & _
    "SERVER=localhost;" & _
    "DATABASE=mydb;" & _
    "USER=user;" & _
    "PASSWORD=password;" & _
    "Option=3"

    'Debug.Print oConn

    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, Err.Source
End Function
```

The ConnectDB function is connecting ok as I am running other scripts
 with it.  If anyone can see what I am doing wrong then any help would
 be appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Garry

Comment: What's the problem, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: Youre writing "query should only return one record" but don't say what actually happens - does it return more than one record or does it return empty resultset? In case of later I quess the `emailAddress` contains value which doesn't exist in the database.

Comment: Sorry guys, the sql returns an empty resultset where it should return one record with one field, the client id.  I have run the SQL through phpMyAdmin and recieved the one record as expected.

Comment: @Garry Well, what is the output of `Debug.Print sql` looks like?

Comment: @ain SELECT client_id FROM clients WHERE email_address = 'valid@email.address' LIMIT 1

Comment: Instead of checking the recordcount, check for EOF instead. Record sets don't always report the correct count directly after opening them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MyODBC does not properly provide the RecordCount-Attribute.

[Re: Problem with RecordCount with ASP & MySQL](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/50198)

[rs.recordcount = -1 with myODBC](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=245287)

[Re: ADO Connection RecordCount](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?37,25644,25649)

So, if you really need the RecordCount, set CursorLocation Property  to adUseClient. 
If not, just iterate through the RecordSet like this:

```
Do While Not rs.EOF
    '...do your magic
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: Thanks cularis, that was the answer.  I changed the check to see if rs(0) contained a vaue greater than zero and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use `"` (double quote) instead of `'` (single quote), because you are querying through the ODBC driver.

Answer (score 0):

This could be problem of driver you have selected. My suggestion is (and I may be wrong) - if you are connecting via ODBC it could have different set of commands.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ondřej, I am using the MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver.  I have added the code to my post above.